# How to solve differential equation $y''=y$ by Fourier series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

How can I solve differential equation $y''=y$ by Fourier series when $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=-2$?

First, I consider the Fourier series $y=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n \cos nx+\sin nx)$, then I get $y''=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-n^2 a_n \sin nx -n^2 b_n \cos nx)$. After that I have $$ \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n \cos nx+\sin nx)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-n^2 a_n \sin nx -n^2 b_n \cos nx)$$.

But now I don't know what to do for obtaining $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: Are you sure the DE is $y''=y$. If it is $y''=-y$ then you can get a solution in terms of sine ans cosine functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This DE does not have a periodic solution valid on $\mathbb R$, so this method fails. The actual solutions is $e^{-x}-e^{x}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you tell me why we can't solve this DE by Fourier series?

Comment: Fourier series is for periodic functions. Since there is no periodic solution to the DE we cannot use Fourier series.

Comment: How can I understand a solution is periodic when it is unknown?